# Wheel event in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I am having an issue with a custom scrolling code, but only on microsoft edge (it even works on IE11): the browser seems to throw multiple wheel events, whether only one "wheel click" is made. Because of that, the page scrolls way too much (to the bottom of the page). Does anyone has a solution for disabling that strange behaviour or get round it ?

The code :

```
$(window).on("wheel", function (e) {
    timer+=.5;
    if(!siID) {
        var siID = setInterval(function () {
            window.scrollBy(0, e.originalEvent.deltaY>0 ? 1 : -1);
            timer -=.01;
            if (timer <= 0) {
                clearInterval(siID);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Same issue here, with MapQuest/ OpenStreetMap/ Leaflet plugin. Windows 10 settings is set to "3 lines per click", and Edge alone of all browsers will zoom three levels when I roll the wheel; all others zoom one level as you'd expect.